# Other buttons in my view are being pressed on button press

Tags: ios, iphone, uibutton

Something strange is happening in my app. I'm finding that when I press any button, all of the other buttons on my view are getting pressed. They all seem to be linked somehow.

There are no outlets connecting them to each other, they're not linked to the same function or anything. I can't figure out why this is happening? Any ideas why pressing one button will trigger a touchupinside event on another, unrelated button?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I bet you created a button, added an action to it, and then duplicated it, dragged the copy to a new location, and added an action to the copy. Then you continued with that process.

Go to the "connections inspector" tab on the right (The circle with an arrow on it). Select each button. I'm guessing that you have multiple actions on each button. (A button can contain multiple actions.)

Comment: Thanks but the connections inspector showed nothing. What's strange is if I put a 1pt constraint around the button, it stops happening. I have a button library that I'm using. I think I'm gonna uninstall the library and see if it makes a difference.